# three questions logging in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging

I have 3 question about logging inside srping

**First**:

spring documentation:

> By default, If you use the ‘Starter POMs’, Logback will be used for
> logging. Appropriate Logback routing is also included to ensure that
> dependent libraries that use Java Util Logging, Commons Logging, Log4J
> or SLF4J will all work correctly.

I don't understand that if a third-party library uses a different logger, what problem will be created in the program? If that library uses another logger, that logger is located as a dependency in its jar file, and when the library is added that logger is also added and there is no problem.

**second**:

I saw in a tutorial that it says that trace and debug are disabled by default in spring because it causes performance problems. I understand why trace is a problem because it must report everything that happens in the program. But why does debug cause performance problems? When I did: debug=true, it didn't take me that much time. So what's the problem?

**Third**:

In this tutorial, it says that logback does not have a FATAL level. Why not? Is it possible that the spring boot program does not have some of the required settings, but it can still start without the need for FATAL?

Answer (score -1):

1. Different logging implementations require different configurations. Log4j uses XML and Java-Util-Log (JUL) uses properties. Also the xml sematics differs.
   So you do not like to configure all logging implementations individually. You like to configure **one** logging configuration to rule them all, one source-of-truth for logging-config. This have nothing to do with the main intend of the software you are running. Later logging-frameworks generalize older logging-frameworks, so you need the latest logging-framework to rule them all.
2. Let me rephrase first: Why do we differ between debug and trace? Debug (or de-bug) is a special condition that let you inspect a bug for debugging purposes. Debug may show clients real-world firstname and family-name, in order to output those informations you need code under debugging-circumstances only. To log them may cause legal problems because you are processing/storing personal informations without permission in log-files. In order to de-bug a software you need the debug-log in 90% of all cases. Only in rare cases you need the trace-log. That meens they differ.
3. Thats a good one. Fatal for me meens the server has hardware problems (burning hard-drive, loose of power supply). This is indicated by errors. Seriously? I have no idea. I may argue that everything that is fatal-worthit should be an error.